# pimpl for protected member during inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, protected, pimpl-idiom

I have a large number of **protected** member function declared in a `Base class hpp file which is used by the *derived* class. My Idea is to remove them from the header file to reduce compilation dependency. I thought of using pimpl method for the protected member as well.

I defined a **Impl** class in *Base* class cpp file and moved all the **protected** function inside the **Impl** class. Further, I did a forward declaration of **Impl** class in *Base* class header file as a protected member.

```
protected:
    class Impl;
    Impl* impl_;
```

But in doing so, when I am calling the protected funtion using *impl_* from *derived* class, following error occurred in derived class compilation::

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Base::Impl’
    if (false == impl_->EncodeMMMsgHeader(mm_msg_header_)) {
error: forward declaration of ‘class Base::Impl’
```

I think the error occurs because can't use a forward declaration in any case where the compiler needs contextual information about the class, nor is it of any use to the compiler to tell it only a little bit about the class.

Is there any way by which I could overcome above problem? If not, then can anyone suggest me a better method to achieve my target.

Comment: protected and virtual methods are part of the interface and shouldn't be hidden in pimpl.

Comment: not sure @Jarod42, protected virtual functions are more often part of the implementation and almost never a part of the interface.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan: Derived classes see and can use `protected` data and can override each `virtual` (non `final`) methods.

Comment: agree, but this does not make it part of interface of the class, quite contrary, it makes them part of implementation

Answer (score 1):

You might add a layer to reduce dependencies:

From

```
#include "lot_of_dependencies"

#include <memory>

class MyClass
{
public:
    ~MyClass();
    /*...*/
protected:
    /* Protected stuff */
private:
    struct Pimpl;
    std::unique_ptr<Pimpl> impl;
};
```

add

## MyClassProtectedStuff.h

```
#include "lot_of_dependencies"

class MyClassProtectedStuff
{
public:
    /* Protected stuff of MyClass */
private:
    // MyClass* owner; // Possibly back pointer
};
```

and then

## MyClass.h

```
#include <memory>

class MyClassProtectedStuff;

class MyClass
{
public:
    ~MyClass();
    /*...*/
protected:
    const MyClassProtectedStuff& GetProtected() const;
    MyClassProtectedStuff& GetProtected();
private:
    struct Pimpl;
    std::unique_ptr<Pimpl> impl;
    std::unique_ptr<MyClassProtectedStuff> protectedData; // Might be in Piml.
};
```

And then derived class should include both headers, whereas regular class only include MyClass.h

Comment: I have another purpose for removing the protected member function from the header file. As I have to include "MyClass.h" header file in a large number of other files which will not require this protected stuff.
Though your idea will work fine it will defeat my above purpose which is equally important.